# Generating a random 32-byte hex integer using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

Hello I posted here yesterday about generating random 16 digits using Qiskit, and a gentle guy helped me but how about a string? How can I generate random 256 bit key in hex format in a superposition state and measure it?

Anyway something like this but using Qiskit instead:

def generate_key():

```
 return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('utf-8').upper()
```

**Output:**
CEF3A7BE7F95F3C27F393C74C99A2C1F1F8C658D3CD973C5FF3C266C7133AA38

Answer (score 1):

A binary string can be converted into other formats such as decimal, octal and as you require, hexadecimal. As you have already mentioned, you need a 256-bit key. So you can replicate the same method as answered in [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26097/generating-a-random-16-digits-in-a-superposition-state-using-qiskit?rq=1) and set the number of qubits to be 256.

Repeat the same procedure and then convert the output to a hex format.

```
import coden
random_bits = get_random_bits(size=256) 
hex_key = coden.bin_to_hex(random_bits)
```

Here, `get_random_bits` will be constructed by you using your knowledge from the answer of the previous question.